# Using Reporting Services Excel data spreadsheet shows ####

Tags: excel, reporting-services

When I export my rdl file to excel the date/time shows up as ######. I researched it and it said to make the columns wider. I got it to work but im on the edge of the page. When I export to pdf everything is messed up because of the width. Is there another way to stop the excel spreadsheet data from showing up as #### other than widening the columns?

Comment: Make the font size smaller, just use date (not time). If the date won't fit in the column, but you can't make it wider, how <i>should</i> it look?

Comment: You can change the precision or formatting of the information in the cells so that it takes up less space.  For instance, go from December 3, 2013 to 2013-12-03, or some other shorter format.

Comment: Merge the columns if the columns next to it are blank.

Comment: @user3056839 Currently it looks like 12/18/2013 3:00:00PM because there is a date last modified field and date last created field and date last validated field that shows the month day hour min and sec

Comment: How come other text fields are able to go to the next line but the date/time cant in excel?

Comment: Is the time portion a requirement? Like @Stewbob says, change the output date format. Even IF the time is needed, you could format it to use 'military time'(?) and remove the PM.

Comment: Also, can you 'steal' space from any other columns? Is there a column with some white space to spare that you can shrink?

Comment: @user3056839 yes time portion is a requirement. And yes I stole space but eventually I had to expand the table which messed up the pdf export. In the pdf file the table becomes too long which skips pages. So it either looks good in excel and not in pdf or vice versa

Comment: @user3056839 I also made the report landscape and I am using 13 inches as the width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How come other text fields are able to go to the next line but the date/time cant in excel?"

Try converting the datetime to string:

=CStr(Format(Fields!Target_Date.Value,"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))

Make sure the format of the textbox is set to 'General', or the Format property is blank.

This will allow the date and time to wrap in the textbox. The downside is excel now thinks this date is a string, which if there is to be no further manipulation of this, should not cause an issue.

Comment: Thank yourself! I doubt I would have thought of that solution without your comment, which is why I quoted it.